# Throwing a custom exception from a nested function C++

Tags: c++, exception

I have custom exception class below:

```
#include <exception>

#pragma once
class MyException : public std::exception
{
public:
    MyException ();
    MyException (std::string message="");
    virtual const char* what()throw();
private:
    std::string m_exceptionMessage;
};
```

The corresponding .cpp file has the right definitions.

Here is how my function is nested:

```
f1();
f2();
void main()
{
   try
   {
      f1();
   }

   catch (std::exception &ex)
   {
      std::cerr << ex.what() << std::endl;
   }
}

void f1()
{
   try
   {
      f2();
   }
   catch (std::exception &ex)
   {
      throw std::exception(ex);
   }
}

void f2()
{
   try
   {
      InitCalculations();
      hr = DoSomething();
      if(hr!=S_OK)
          throw MyException ("invalid argument")
   }
   catch (std::exception &ex)
   {
      throw std::exception(ex);
   }

}
```

I have tried to summarize the problem. All the functions lie in different files under different headers. I get the right message pass to the first catch in function `f2()`, however as I try to propagate this message, I lose it in `f1()` and hence in `main()`
What is the right way to propagate the exception coming from `f2()` to the `main()` function?

Comment: Why are you catching the exception if all you do is "re-throw" it (except incorrectly because you construct a new object of the parent class, not the custom class)?

Comment: `#pragma once` must be the first line in your file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`throw std::exception(ex);` creates a new exception object which is not `MyException` any more. That's why you lose the message. You need to use just `throw;`, it rethrows the existing caught exception.

And, btw. you shouldn't use `std::string` nor any other object which allocates from heap inside your exception. Program might have thrown exception because of not enough memory and `std::string` will then throw another one because it cannot allocate buffer, causing your program to exit.

Use `const char *` literal and if you need variable text use statically allocated `char[]` buffer and populate it with `sprintf()`.

Comment: Derive from [`std::runtime_error`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/runtime_error) instead of `std::exception` directly. `std:runtime_error` takes both `char*` and `std::string` as input, and implements `what()` for you.